# Using optional (keyword) arguments in (C callable) cdef method in Cython

Tags: cython, optional-arguments

Is it possible to define a (C callable) method (so via `cdef` instead of `def`) with keyword arguments, e.g.

```
cdef double function(x, **kwargs):
    if "factor" in kwargs:
        x = x * kwargs["factor"]
    return x*2
```

I know I could split the function into two parts: one def with the `**kwargs` which is calling the cdef function.
Currently I'm trying to have the same source code for Python and Cython with some additional [pyorcy](https://github.com/markolopa/pyorcy) lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `cdef` functions generate a C-style function signature and there's no real way to represent keyword arguments in that.

You could have the function accept a dictionary which you effectively treat as keyword arguments:

```
cdef double function(x, kwargs):
    # the rest as before
```

---

Why do you want a `cdef` function? `def` functions defined within Cython are still compiled and can do most of the same things `cdef` functions can, so there's little reason to make your functions `cdef` unless you find you have to.

Comment: I thought it would be faster. After a benchmark test I figured out it is not. Thanks anyway